# Let $K$ be a ring. Then $K[X_1,X_2] \cong K[X_1][X_2]$

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

This is a lemma from textbook **Analysis I** by *Amann/Escher*. I present my attempt below. Does it look fine or contain gaps/errors? Thank you for your verification!

> Let $K$ be a ring. Then $K[X_1,X_2] \cong K[X_1][X_2]$.

---

**My attempt:**

We define a mapping $\psi: K[X_1,X_2] \to K[X_1][X_2]$ by $\psi(f)=g$ where $g(n)(m) := f(n,m)$ for $(n,m) \in \Bbb N^2$. It is not hard to verify that $\psi$ is bijective.

Let $f_,f_2 \in K[X_1,X_2]$ and $(n,m) \in \Bbb N^2$.

We have

$$\begin{align}\psi(f_1 + f_2)(n)(m) &= (f_1 + f_2)(n,m)\\ &= f_1(n,m) + f_2(n,m)\\ &= g_1(n)(m) + g_2(n)(m)\\ &= (g_1(n)+g_2(n))(m)\\ &= (g_1+g_2)(n)(m) \\ &= (\psi(f_1) + \psi(f_2))(n)(m)\end{align}$$

Thus $\psi(f_1 + f_2) = \psi(f_1) + \psi(f_2)$.

Moreover,

$$\begin{align}\psi(f_1 \cdot f_2)(n)(m) &= (f_1 \cdot f_2)(n,m)\\ &= \sum_{(p,q) \le (n,m)}[f_1(p,q) + f_2((n,m) - (p,q))]\\ &= \sum_{(p,q) \le (n,m)}[g_1(p)(q) + g_2(n-p)(m-q)]\\ &= \\ &= \sum_{p \le n} \sum_{q \le m}[g_1(p)(q) + g_2(n-p)(m-q)]\\ &= \sum_{p \le n} [(g_1(p) \cdot g_2(n-p))(m)]\\ &=\left(\sum_{p \le n}[g_1(p) \cdot g_2(n-p)]\right)(m)\\ &= (g_1 \cdot g_2)(n)(m) \\ &=(\psi(f_1) \cdot \psi(f_2))(n)(m)\end{align}$$

Thus $\psi(f_1 \cdot f_2) = \psi(f_1) \cdot \psi(f_2)$.

As a result, $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I don't understand why you use $\mathbb{N}$ here? We can always consider a polynomial in $K[x][y]$ as a polynomial in $K[y]$ with coefficients coming from $K[x]$ (as $K[x]$ is a ring so we can form a polynomial ring over it). For example, $2x^2y^3+4xy^2+3y+2x$ can be seen as $ (2x^2)y^3+ (4x)y^2+(3)y + (2x)$. Note here all terms in the bracket come from $K[x]$. From here I think one can construct an isomorphism.

Comment: @MayankMishra My textbook defines ring of formal power series as [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Formal_power_series#/Definition_of_the_formal_power_series_ring). That comes the presence of $\Bbb N$. Please have a look.

Comment: Hmm, I see it now :)

Comment: Thank you for your interest @MayankMishra ;)